# Colorplot in python with smoother resolution without interpolating

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to plot a 2D matrix into a color plot using python. However the plot comes out highly pixelated. How do I make the color transitions look smoother ***without*** increasing data size, decreasing figure size or applying interpolation ?

For example, consider the below dummy plot

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

H = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
          [5, 6, 7, 8],
          [9, 10, 11, 12],
          [13, 14, 15, 16]])

plt.imshow(H)
plt.show()
```

This gives the following colorplot. As you can see its highly pixelated. By *pixelated* I mean that one can see the individual data points. I want a plot where the colors are sort of blended together. I tried to propose using `interpolation = "bicubic"` parameter in `plt.imshow()`, but I was rejected since interpolating the data changes the values. So, how else do I do this ?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want to smooth the colours, without interpolation, because if you interpolate, the resulting figure doesn't show the correct values? In that case, wouldn't smoothing the gradient also change the values?

Comment: Trust me I don't understand either, I am at my wit's end.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest talking with whoever is rejecting your graphs. Discussing requirements with customers is always important and often they themselves might not know exactly what they want either. Good luck!